# How does Objective-c handle messages sent to nil objects?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, message, null

I know it's ok to send the `release` message to nil objects.  **What about other messages?**  The following code prints `0` to the console.  I'd like to understand why.

```
NSArray *a = nil;
int i = [a count];
NSLog(@"%d", i);
```

Does sending messages to `nil` objects ever cause errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objc_msgSend()` effectively drops messages to `nil`. If the method has a non-`void` return type, it will return something like `nil`, i.e. `0`, `NO`, or `0.0`, although [this isn't always guaranteed all return types on all platforms](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/05/29/nil/).  Thus, the only errors you're likely to encounter are when your object isn't really nil, (e.g. when it's a reference to a deallocated object), or when you don't handle nil as a return type appropriately.

In your example, `-count` returns an `NSUInteger`, so the value of `i` will be `0`, since `objc_msgSend()` will return `0` for a message to `nil` that should return an `NSUInteger`.

Answer (score 6):

Return values from messages to `nil` objects are guaranteed to return the equivalent of zero for scalar return types, i.e., `nil`, `0`, `0.0`, `NO`, etc.

See here: [Sending Messages to nil](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7).